# Finding root directory in web.config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to find the root directory of my aspx application. The scenario is a user is trying to login to a subfolder of my root. I want them to be redirected to a login page inside of another folder.

I'm trying to handle this inside of the root web.config file, but the compiler is looking inside of the subfolder from which the user is trying to login from.

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="~/auth/login.aspx" name="loginform">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
```

is the directory i'm trying to get to but it is still looking inside of the app folder, not the root directory.

Here is what i am getting

```
/Apps/subfolder/auth/login.aspx
```

and this is what i want

```
/Apps/auth/login.aspx
```

keep in mind that /Apps/ is the root directory.

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

This value is being superceded by a value elsewhere in the code. Maybe the web.config in the subdirectory where the page the user tries to view before being sent to login is held.